# How change vscode specific language colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to use VS code to handle the Siemens SIMOTION ST code, in this way I can use the power of vscode, that is missing in the original editor (multi line selection, select a word and find immediately where that word is used etc).
To do that I would like to match the ST code color as the original editor, to avoid confusion.

At the end I need to copy the vs code in the original editor to perform the download.

Where I can find the rules used for the ST code and generate a new language code?

The text colors are set in the theme area or I can handle it also from the language `package.json`?

I would like to match the ST color scheme in vscode as it is in SIMOTION SCOUT without compromise all the others code/theme colors.

Comment: looking at the original editor images it is just a few keywords, comments and numbers, a very simple TextMate grammar file, you can customize the colors of the theme used in `settings.json`

Comment: @rioV8 but I would like to don't change the color theme in case of others programmation code, it's possible to contain the color scheme for each language?

Comment: no, the TextMate scopes have a color defined in the theme, this way all languages use the same color for keywords, variables, comment, ...., you can't customize the theme color based on language, or you could set theme customization in the workspace settings file that use the language